# Complex analysis basics

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, complex-numbers

If I *z = x + yi* and *w = f(z)*, describe the image R of D in the w-plane when 
$$0<x<\pi/2, 0<y<\infty;w = e^{iz}$$
Wouldn't this mean that in the w-plane the argument *arg(w) = $\infty$* would just go "round and round" into infinity?

I'm just starting out in complex analysis, so bear with me if this is too basic.

Comment: It would if it had been $w=e^z$. Mind you, there is an $i$ in the exponent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

$f(z) = e^{iz} = e^{-y + ix}$

Think about this expression under the constraints of $x, y$

**Update**

Any $z$ can be represented as $z=Re^{i\theta}$ where $R$ is its distance from the origin and $\theta$ is the angle with the $x$-axis.

For $f$ we have $f(z) = e^{-y + ix} = e^{-y}e^{ix}$. We know that $y>0$ and that $0 \lt x \lt \pi/2$. What does this tell you about $e^{-y}e^{ix}$

Comment: Does it get mapped to a straight line in the polar plane? Like the y-axis?

Comment: @fadaes please see my update

Comment: All the points in a distance 1 from (0,0) with an angle between 0 and $\pi/2$?

Comment: @fadaes no. since $y>0$ we have $0<e^{-y}<1$. so these are all the points with distance between $0$ and $1$ and angle between $0$ and $\pi/2$

Comment: Oh, sorry that's what I meant really:) Thank you!